# SUM and IIF statements are not giving results in Text Values

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, sum, iif

I am creating a report using Report Builder 3.0 SQL Server 2008 R2. One Form there is a check box, when checked it save Yes in view/table and if not checked it save No in view/table. When Checked, I need to print a text statement on report and if not checked then I need to print another field's value. If I use the following expression:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!CheckekBox_Checked.Value="Yes", 1,0) ,"DataSet1")
```

it prints 1, when checked and print 0 when not checked. Works fine.
but when I use the following expression:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!CheckekBox_Checked.Value="Yes", "CHECKBOX is CHECKED", Fields!Address.Value) ,"DataSet1")
```

It didn't print anything but `#Error` (as text) on report. There is no error while saving the report. Can you please help me to correct the syntax?

Comment: The function Sum() takes numeric arguments you are passing a string `"CHECKBOX is CHECKED"`. Try change the string by 1, and Address field for 0.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I have to pass the string. Value of address field is also a string. It seems like I should not use SUM, but what else, how can I accomplish this task?

Comment: What is your expected result? If you have to show the sum and the address you can concatenate these values.

Comment: well, I just need to show the string/text values. Never need to show any sum, just the string value. [If check box is checked, will show some string, and if not checked then will show some string. No Sum/Numeric]

Comment: ALRIGHT, FINALLY I FOUND A SOLUTION...
I used the following code, and it worked fine for me

=Switch(First(Fields!CheckekBox_Checked.Value, "DataSet1")="Yes", "CHECKBOX IS CHECKED" , First(Fields!CheckekBox_Checked.Value, "DataSet1")="No", First(Fields!Address.Value, "DataSet1"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is an example of what you would run to count how many instances of a condition are present. For example, you want to know how many checkboxes are checked? It will return a "1" for every check box that is checked and then add them all together to give you a total count of how many are checked.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!CheckekBox_Checked.Value="Yes", 1,0) ,"DataSet1")
```

When you run the below code, you are telling your expression to return the text "CHECKBOX is CHECKED" whenever the expression is true or return the "address" value when it is not. When it is done, you're telling it to add all "CHECKBOX is CHECKED" and address values. What's "CHECKBOX is CHECKED" plus "CHECKBOX is CHECKED"? An error, that's what.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!CheckekBox_Checked.Value="Yes", "CHECKBOX is CHECKED", Fields!Address.Value) ,"DataSet1")
```

Comment: Actually on my Input Window/Form, there is only one checkbox. Which I need to print on the report, if it is checked or some other field's value when not checked. I m new to report writing, still unable to resolve the issue. Please guide...

Comment: In both cases, the value of other field or a text, is actually STRING value or text. so how to display text or string on both cases if that one checkbox is checked or not...